# Array Append Problems - Swift

Tags: swift

I add the data I pulled from the database to Array. I add these arrays I added in an array. But it doesn't add it the way I want it, where am I doing it wrong?

[["...xyz/Uploads/fnzo1PcnjH3M-1653.jpg"], ["...xyz/Uploads/fnzo1PcnjH3M-1653.jpg", "....xyz/Uploads/Kb6kbOQNY0Vi-1670.png"], [...xyz/Uploads/fnzo1PcnjH3M-1653.jpg", "....xyz/Uploads/Kb6kbOQNY0Vi-1670.png", "...xyz/Uploads/PQASvz4ipg9s-1673.jpg"]]

The output is like this but it should be what I want:

[["...xyz/Uploads/fnzo1PcnjH3M-1653.jpg", "...xyz/Uploads/fnzo1PcnjH3M-1653.jpg", "....xyz/Uploads/Kb6kbOQNY0Vi-1670.png"], ["...xyz/Uploads/fnzo1PcnjH3M-1653.jpg", "....xyz/Uploads/Kb6kbOQNY0Vi-1670.png", "...xyz/Uploads/PQASvz4ipg9s-1673.jpg"]]

So the first array is the davetiyefilee array, the second array is the davetiyefilee2 array. The combination of these arrays is the model array. 
So : model = [[davetiyefilee], [davetiyefilee2]]

**CODE**

```
var model = [[String]]()
var davetiyefilee = [String]()
var davetiyefilee2 = [String]()

@objc func davetiyecek2() {
    if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
       for review in baslik {
          if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
             let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
             self.davetiyefilee2.append(s)
             self.model.append(self.davetiyefilee2)                           
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.refreshNow = true
                self.tableVieww.reloadData()
             } 
          } 
       } 
   } 
}

@objc func davetiyeCEK1() {
    if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
       for review in baslik {
           if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
              let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
              self.davetiyefilee.append(s)
              self.model.append(self.davetiyefilee)
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.refreshNow = true
                  self.tableVieww.reloadData()
              } 
           } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to append the inner array to the outer array **after** the loop.

Reloading the table view inside a loop again and again is bad practice anyway.

And where is the `do - catch` block?

```
var model = [[String]]()
var davetiyefilee = [String]()
var davetiyefilee2 = [String]()
@objc func davetiyecek2() {
    do {
        if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] {
           for review in baslik {
              if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
                 let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                 self.davetiyefilee2.append(s)
              }
           }
           self.model.append(self.davetiyefilee2)                           
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.refreshNow = true
              self.tableVieww.reloadData()
           }  
       } 
   } catch { print(error) } 
}

@objc func davetiyeCEK1() {
    do {
        if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] {
           for review in baslik {
               if let soru_baslik = review["davetiyefilee"] as? String {
                  let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                  self.davetiyefilee.append(s)
               }
           }
           self.model.append(self.davetiyefilee)
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.refreshNow = true
               self.tableVieww.reloadData()
           } 
       }
   } catch { print(error) } 
}
```